# How to redirect to Coming Soon template

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect http://example.com to coming-soon.html template, but not index.html.

Possible to do it in route settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying to cover the site from the public while working on it live, i personally would name my coming soon template file `503.html`

Then in the General Settings section of the control panel, switch System Status off.

That way so long as you are logged in, you can access the site as normal but anyone else visiting your site will see the contents of the `503.html` template.

Comment: Never noticed this feature, good find! There's even a setting in user group rights to allow login while the site is off. While building the site you can `include` the coming-soon.html and later switch to a proper 503.

Comment: Note that page status code returned 503. Probably not the best option for a coming soon page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `redirect` [tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect). Put this in your `index.html` template:

```
{% redirect "coming-soon" %}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to stay on the homepage but want to show the template code for another page, you can use [Twig include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html). Put this in your `index.html` template:

```
{% include "coming-soon" %}
```

Alternatively, just put your Coming Soon template code straight onto `index.html`? Either way, this answer should cover everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for this method.
But this will show http://example.com/coming-soon. What if i just want the url link http://example.com/

Comment: Right ok, that's not really a re-direct then as you are staying on the homepage, but showing content from another page. I have updated my answer with another method.

Comment: Oops.
Sorry my question not specific enough.
Yeah, currently I place all my code coming soon code in index.html.
I thought can do it in the route setting then easy for me set back later.
Thanks alot. =)

Comment: @HsTung No problem at all, glad to help!